# IMPORTXML not updating for unknown reason

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

Doing a web scrapping exercise I found that after I was able to view the table in the aim sheet with `IMPORTXML` the formula stopped pulling/scrapping and an #N/A tag show up in its place.

[image]

Comment: what does the **#N/A** error say?

Comment: After I changing the XML dependencies it seemed to stayed querying..I only eliminated the thead tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove **`=`** operator
- press **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
- and then again add **`=`**

```
=IMPORTXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EAEX/components?p=%5EAEX", "//thead/tr")
```

[image]

Comment: This seemed to give me what I want...
=IMPORTXML( "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EAEX/components?p=%5EAEX","//tr")

I will need to learn XML properly to use dependencies accordingly. tnx man

Comment: that worked great..tnx @user0